# How do I get a complete list of files in my hard drive in a convenient format?

Tags: hard-drive, mint

My hard drive is about to fail and I'm about to get a new one. Most of my files are not really personal and is mostly downloaded off from the internet. 
So as a countermeasure, I wanted to get a complete list of files in my hard drive that is easy to search through in case the hard drive failed earlier (so that I can re-download it later on).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may be interested only in your /home/ directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**(using `find`)

```
find /path/to/the/directory >~/file.txt
```

**Method 2** (using tree package)

```
sudo apt-get install tree
tree -fi /path/to/the/directory >~/file.txt
```

use

```
tree -fia /path/to/the/directory >~/file.txt
```

for hidden files also

Here the you will find all the filenames in a file called file.txt at `~`

**Method 3**(Using Bash)

Execute this from `/path/to/the/directory`(Thats is if you want all files under home , If you want something else change accordingly)

that is

```
cd /path/to/the/directory
ls -R --group-directories-first >~/file.txt
```

Here the you will find all the filenames in a file called `file.txt` at `~`

**Method 4**(Using python)

Execute this python script and you will get a file called `newfile.txt` with all the contents in /home directory

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import fnmatch
path = '/home'
configfiles = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path)
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.*')]
with open("newfile.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for files in configfiles:
        fp.write(files+"\n")
```

Comment: For the second method, how do we choose the directory we want to use?

Comment: `tree -fi <directory path> >~/files.txt` . I have updated the answer.